# Where can I find a Chinese common phrase database?

Tags: phrase, database

I'm looking for a Chinese common phrase database for my project, where can I find something like this?

```
阿姨
菠菜
大法
风格
动物
森林
窗口
打开
回复
重播
```

Comment: phrase database? for example sentences containing words in list see jukuu, line dictionary, examples

Comment: @user6065 not a database where I can look up words, but simply a list of common words/phrases in plain text.

Comment: http://www.cp.com.cn/book/91f93016-f.html https://gist.github.com/indiejoseph/eae09c673460aa0b56db The two are not the same. I don't know how accurate the second is.

Comment: Download a Chinese input software, then output the dictionary. I like to use QQ wubi, It can output 100,000 entries.

Answer (score 2):

The Ministry of Education in Taiwan provides [some statistics](http://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/files/SITE_CONTENT/M0001/PIN/yu7.htm?open).

> 表一：字頻總表
>   Table 1: Character frequency
>
> 表二：[詞頻總表](http://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/files/SITE_CONTENT/M0001/PIN/biau2.htm?open)
>   Table 2: Phrase frequency
>
> 表三：本字彙部首出現情形說明表：依二一四部首序排列
>   Table 3: Radicals, sorted by radical
>
> 表四：本字彙部首出現情形說明表：依部首使用頻次高低序排列
>   Table 4: Radicals, sorted by frequency
>
> 表 五：本字彙表筆畫出現情形說明表：依筆畫多寡序排列
>   Table 5: Strokes, sorted by the number of strokes
>
> 表 六：本字彙表筆畫出現情形說明表：依各筆畫使用高低序排列
>   Table 6: Strokes, sorted by frequency
>
> 表 七：本字彙表音節統計表
>   Table 7: Syllable statistics
>
> 表 八：本字彙表聲母符號出現情形說明表
>   Table 8: Consonant statistics
>
> 表 九：本字彙表韻母符號出現情形說明表
>   Table 9: Vowel statistics
>
> 表 十：本字彙表聲調符號出現情形說明表
>   Table 10: Tone statistics
>
> 表十一：本字彙表聲、韻出現頻次次比對表：依出現頻次高低序排列
>   Table 11: Consonants vs. vowels, sorted by frequency
>
> 表十二：本字彙表聲母符號發聲方法出現頻次統計表
>   Table 12: Pronunciation methods of the consonants
>
> 表十三：本字彙表韻母符號發音方法出現頻次統計表
>   Table 13: Pronunciation methods of the vowels
>
> 表十四：本字彙表構詞率統計表：依詞頭出現頻次排列
>   Table 14: The first character of a phrase, sorted by frequency
>
> 表十五：本字彙表構詞率統計表：依詞尾出現頻次排列
>   Table 15: The last word of a phrase, sorted by frequency
>
> 表十六：本字彙表構詞率統計表：依總構詞率排列
>   Table 16: The word frequency in a phrase
>
> 表十七： 本字彙表與《常用國字標準字體表》比對表： 字頻表與常用字表共有之字
>   Table 17: Characters shown in both Table 1 and the Common Character Table
>
> 表十八：本字彙表與《常用國字標準字體表》比對表： 字頻表與常用字表未共有之字
>   Table 18: Characters shown in Table 1, but not in the Common Character Table
>
> 表十九：本字彙表與《常用國字標準字體表》比對表： 常用字表收字未見於本字彙表之字
>   Table 19: Characters shown in the Common Character Table, but not in Table 1

What you are looking for is the Table 2.
You can download it by clicking the [下載](http://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/files/SITE_CONTENT/M0001/biau2!.exe) link.
It is a self-extracting .exe file.

There are 64326 phrases in the table, which are sorted by frequency in descending order.
For your convenience, I copy the first thousand phrases and convert them to the simplified Chinese.

These statistics were made by MOE in Taiwan long time ago, therefore
they are in traditional Chinese of course;
the encoding may be in BIG5;
the symbols of pronunciation are [bopomofo, ㄅㄆㄇㄈ](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%A8%E9%9F%B3%E7%AC%A6%E8%99%9F);
there are no recent phrases, especially the slang;
[some phrases are different](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E5%9C%B0%E5%8C%BA%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%8D%E5%B7%AE%E5%BC%82%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8) from those in Mainland; and
the syntax of the htm files is different.

If you want to read the Web pages,
save the pages first;
open with a text editor;
find the first "width";
remove the "%" in the values;
save the file; and
open with a Web browser.

---

我们, 台湾, 可以, 自己, 他们, 没有, 因为, 可能, 如果, 问题, 因此, 生活, 什么, 工作, 孩子, 美国, 广告, 经济, 社会, 活动, 开始, 大陆, 世界, 日本, 国小, 但是, 发展, 时间, 市场, 朋友, 公司, 电影, 儿童, 中国, 小朋友, 由于, 所以, 知道, 现在, 许多, 政府, 发现, 成为, 教育, 虽然, 认为, 企业, 地方, 必须, 如何, 目前, 不过, 影响, 已经, 政治, 投资, 就是, 关系, 未来, 重要, 出现, 引擎, 希望, 研究, 北市, 学生, 设计, 时候, 文化, 表现, 国家, 发生, 安全, 进行, 其他, 环境, 表示, 无法, 方式, 需要, 国内, 老师, 方面, 使用, 甚至, 今天, 国际, 一样, 同时, 而且, 非常, 这样, 成长, 一定, 一般, 历史, 相当, 当时, 过去, 举行, 然而, 应该, 台北, 故事, 总统, 电脑, 空间, 大家, 妈妈, 如此, 作品, 结果, 部分, 土地, 今年, 主要, 自然, 特别, 学校, 其中, 产生, 传统, 增加, 为什么, 产品, 提供, 举办, 中心, 比赛, 决定, 最后, 情况, 参加, 这些, 喜欢, 系统, 方法, 健康, 只有, 以及, 生命, 家庭, 比较, 能力, 经验, 时代, 造成, 技术, 艺术, 世纪, 是否, 地球, 出来, 管理, 快乐, 容易, 地区, 汽车, 运动, 成功, 怎么, 机会, 只是, 完全, 这个, 选择, 事实, 人员, 觉得, 先生, 开发, 经过, 东西, 感觉, 对于, 改变, 香港, 所有, 当然, 利用, 个人, 之后, 然后, 真正, 推出, 过程, 环保, 不断, 服务, 接受, 这种, 可是, 中共, 进入, 告诉, 一直, 其实, 动物, 经营, 人民, 另外, 一些, 包括, 去年, 于是, 注意, 组织, 开放, 父亲, 年代, 生产, 形成, 政策, 新加坡, 十分, 只要, 计划, 现象, 欧洲, 那么, 原因, 人类, 音乐, 精神, 一起, 成立, 教学, 要求, 任何, 指出, 严重, 继续, 处理, 父母, 例如, 学习, 品质, 国民党, 选举, 以后, 民众, 现代, 观念, 女性, 人生, 代表, 科学, 拥有, 功能, 了解, 似乎, 治疗, 相信, 几乎, 制度, 标准, 解决, 引起, 完成, 认识, 即使, 交通, 高市, 逐渐, 电视, 压力, 病人, 目标, 努力, 竞争, 建立, 根据, 都是, 台北市, 影片, 终于, 欢迎, 母亲, 保护, 获得, 医生, 人们, 准备, 大学, 一切, 女人, 自由, 尤其, 英国, 帮助, 也许, 后来, 合作, 还有, 身体, 美元, 面对, 提出, 提高, 业者, 价值, 专业, 不仅, 车型, 看到, 上市, 反应, 支持, 科技, 变化, 银行, 才能, 北县, 单位, 调查, 变成, 心理, 分析, 此外, 长期, 减少, 还是, 民主, 别人, 也是, 值得, 电话, 力量, 充满, 观众, 展开, 资金, 爸爸, 人物, 策略, 厂商, 民间, 事业, 超过, 声音, 同样, 青少年, 信托, 配备, 实际, 全国, 并且, 法国, 方向, 以前, 因素, 宇宙, 专家, 创作, 存在, 作用, 建设, 痛苦, 加强, 食物, 观察, 全球, 至于, 城市, 演出, 改革, 附近, 原来, 产业, 距离, 显示, 起来, 意义, 民进党, 直接, 重视, 资料, 性能, 高雄, 报导, 制造, 销售, 角色, 教授, 不再, 旅游, 控制, 积极, 亲子, 仍然, 建议, 太阳, 智慧, 资源, 游戏, 说明, 你们, 改善, 或许, 建筑, 教师, 媒体, 系列, 员工, 基本, 成本, 有关, 明显, 共同, 具有, 资讯, 男人, 股市, 得到, 医院, 成绩, 速度, 景气, 实在, 避免, 形象, 条件, 规划, 会议, 态度, 导演, 行为, 两岸, 美丽, 重新, 检查, 多少, 令人, 左右, 招生, 状况, 设备, 内容, 各种, 客户, 时期, 掌握, 曾经, 自我, 车身, 享受, 妇女, 价格, 立委, 死亡, 往往, 表演, 效果, 眼睛, 大量, 正式, 有些, 车系, 能够, 推动, 医师, 杂志, 通常, 人口, 公里, 保持, 降低, 这里, 德国, 调整, 考虑, 配合, 爱滋病, 办法, 小时, 行动, 情形, 集团, 感染, 独立, 简单, 那些, 每天, 业务, 所谓, 动力, 参与, 唯一, 工程, 不论, 公尺, 事件, 状态, 维持, 上海, 年轻, 家长, 结束, 制作, 加入, 永远, 经堂, 趋势, 知识, 不但, 星系, 特殊, 结构, 有效, 负责, 训练, 强调, 期间, 介绍, 以为, 儿子, 计划, 面临, 患者, 新闻, 工业, 困难, 突然, 追求, 实施, 机构, 谢谢, 小孩, 分别, 吸引, 官员, 相同, 女儿, 成熟, 缺乏, 离开, 少年, 地位, 利益, 事情, 根本, 创造, 报告, 失去, 申请, 持续, 校园, 创意, 运用, 读者, 生存, 安排, 明年, 基础, 统一, 提升, 整个, 中央, 文学, 平均, 都市, 发挥, 程度, 需求, 呈现, 冠军, 大约, 消费者, 清楚, 规定, 肯定, 森林, 登场, 人才, 品牌, 看见, 疾病, 人士, 今日, 水准, 目的, 名单, 阶段, 扩大, 心情, 生物, 校长, 毕业, 这是, 团体, 公布, 全部, 玻璃, 习惯, 证明, 正确, 民国, 全面, 空气, 特色, 感受, 不可, 本身, 正常, 回家, 如今, 西方, 那里, 相关, 风格, 透过, 绝对, 丰富, 反而, 参观, 国中, 理想, 达到, 学者, 一旦, 明天, 发表, 中国人, 印象, 良好, 当地, 公开, 好像, 属于, 有趣, 利率, 首先, 规模, 担心, 车种, 恐龙, 接触, 大众, 主管, 采用, 垃圾, 金融, 思想, 研习, 讨论, 轻松, 导致, 内部, 来自, 小学, 教室, 这么, 解释, 道路, 整体, 北京, 色彩, 行销, 花莲, 消失, 结合, 总经理, 挑战, 坚持, 部门, 兴趣, 总是, 丈夫, 回来, 法律, 原本, 从事, 获利, 怎样, 高中, 数学, 公园, 方案, 流行, 常常, 教部, 寻找, 贸易, 进口, 烦恼, 担任, 角度, 思考, 无论, 对象, 休闲, 植物, 适合, 它们, 我国, 消费, 情绪, 报纸, 紧张, 模式, 有时, 李登辉, 亚洲, 或者, 原则, 马力, 国外, 意见, 鼓励, 范围, 大部分, 充分, 限制, 办理, 聪明, 重大, 海外, 辅导, 人体, 危机, 青年, 相对, 接近, 采取, 暑假, 竞赛, 显然, 快速, 皇帝, 执行, 沟通, 确定, 大自然, 欢乐, 小心, 幼稚园, 名字, 稳定, 轿车, 自杀, 迅速, 到底, 家人, 破坏, 动作, 商品, 访问, 尽管, 下来, 比例, 立即, 再度, 回收, 西元, 星期, 阳光, 预算, 购买, 关键, 愿意, 大多数, 幼儿, 至少, 否则, 刺激, 争取, 恢复, 展现, 时刻, 症状, 商业, 意识, 爱情, 语言, 颜色, 老人, 差异, 针对, 措施, 晚上, 报名, 发行, 照片, 台北县, 类似, 天下, 出国, 同意, 背景, 数字, 确实, 观点, 加速, 正是, 而已, 车款, 或是, 长大, 看法, 博士, 对方, 台商, 权力, 不错, 危险, 回答, 投入, 股票, 信心, 节目, 台中, 澳洲, 各地, 成果, 考试, 免费, 受到, 妻子, 昨天, 现实, 跑车, 瞭解, 绘画, 关心, 只能, 民族, 取得, 房地产, 突破, 尊重, 普遍, 办公室, 婴儿, 工厂, 失败, 房子, 物质, 旅行, 讯息, 感情, 一生, 工具, 自动, 身上, 咖啡, 里面, 农民, 卫生, 分钟, 至今, 家族, 记者, 培养, 贷款, 进步, 实验, 复杂, 收入, 形式, 找到, 投资人, 男性, 依然, 夏天, 著名, 爱心, 经费, 人数, 小姐, 交易, 老板, 呼吸, 彼此, 计算, 气氛, 采访, 暴力, 器官, 大幅, 子女, 主题, 合理, 车子, 协助, 英文, 执政党, 符合, 演员, 之前, 位置, 保险, 纷纷, 设立, 整合, 礼物, 不管, 牙齿, 扭力, 玩具, 高雄市, 深入, 戏剧, 关怀, 严格, 反映, 立刻, 年龄, 行政, 衣服, 每年, 始终, 明白, 东京, 面积, 区域, 画面, 想像, 董事长, 预测, 演讲, 庆祝, 操作, 营养, 职棒, 下降, 大概, 反对, 主人, 同学, 即将, 吸收, 飞机, 组合, 造型, 项目, 意外, 照顾, 达成, 实力, 主任, 全省, 地点, 拍摄, 明星, 表面, 家里, 概念, 当年, 药物, 互相, 必要, 欣赏, 股价, 表达, 前往, 记得, 伟大, 义大利, 补助, 满足, 心灵, 打开, 成就, 早期, 并非, 命运, 星星, 重点, 气门, 马上, 强烈, 障碍, 激烈, 联合国, 关于, 少数, 巨大, 本来, 回忆, 批评, 究竟, 教厅, 深刻, 组成, 图书馆, 领域, 引进, 心中, 作者, 作业, 防止, 科学家, 预防, 舞蹈, 热闹, 悬挂, 小说, 以往, 平衡, 彷佛

---

The MOE also had [the statistics for the textbooks of the primary schools in Mainland](http://language.moe.gov.tw/001/Upload/files/SITE_CONTENT/M0001/MAINLAND/ch2.htm?open).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a word list for input method:

https://github.com/dongxiexidian/Chinese/blob/master/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%E8%AF%8D%E5%BA%93%E6%95%B4%E7%90%86/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E5%88%86%E8%AF%8D%E8%AF%8D%E5%BA%93%E6%95%B4%E7%90%86/%E5%9B%9B%E5%8D%81%E4%B8%87%E5%8F%AF%E7%94%A8%E6%90%9C%E7%8B%97txt%E8%AF%8D%E5%BA%93.txt

400 thousand words, that's enough for whatever purpose.

Comment: Those words are sorted by alphabetical order instead of popularity. I just need some a few thousand common words.